# How to implement the idea of maxFlex

Tags: css, flexbox

I am looking for a way to implement the following pseudo-code:

```
// container
<div style={{ height: 1000px; display: flex; }}>
    // top view
    <div style={{ flex: 1}}>
        // Some child A
    </div>

    // bottom view
    <div style={{ maxFlex: 1 }}> // however, maxFlex does not exist
        // Some child B
    </div>
</div>
```

**The following example should get the behaviour across**
Suppose the container is 1000px. If child B has a height greater than 500px, the bottom div should be capped at 500px (which would be the case anyway when using `flex: 1`).
If however the size of child B is x < 500px, then the bottom div should shrink to x. At the same time the top div should take all available space and become 500+(500-x) px.

I am looking for a flex approach, not a solution that uses `maxHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is place a container inside of `flex:1` container. By doing so, `.inner-bottom` will take the size and height of it's parent.

### HTML:

```html
      <div class='bottom'>
        <div class='inner-bottom'>
          abc<br />
          abc<br />
          abc<br />
          abc<br />
          abc<br />
          abc<br />
          abc<br />
         <!-- try running with and without these -->
<!--         abc<br />  
        abc<br />
        abc<br />
        abc<br />  -->
        </div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: 'red';
  height: 300px;
  /* overflow: scroll; */
}

.top {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  background-color: #ffb8b8;
}

.bottom {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.inner-bottom {
  background-color: #bab8ff;
}
```

Here's a link to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) explaining it

Comment: Your suggested approach will not make the second View smaller when it should. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8bw0ade1/24/

Comment: edited! here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aypsf3xv/2/

Comment: Getting there! As the top div has `flex: 1` I would like it to take all available space, that is, the green area that becomes 'available' when the bottom div is smaller, should be taken up by the top div. I might have to edit my question to get that point more across.

Comment: what needs to be in the top box? What exactly are you trying to do here/what's the point. Kinda hard to take a contrived example like this without knowing all the edge cases

Comment: why can't we use `maxHeight` here? Is there something against that or what?

Comment: In the 'real' case the top container is the leading view. It contains a scroll view that will usually overflow and should therefore take all available space. The bottom view will appear only when incurred by the user. It also contains a scrollview that may vary in size. Not being the 'leading' view it should at most be of equal height as the leading view, but when possible smaller.

Comment: As for not using maxHeight: this is all wrapped in a keyboard avoiding view. This adds margin to the bottom view. This changes the available space. Something that flex works very good with. maxHeight however does not.